# Regex: Case-insensitive Matching with Case-sensitive Exceptions

Tags: php, regex, regex-group, string-matching, case-sensitive

**Use case:** I have a large bulk of text I need to match, line by line, against a large list of terms to audit for consistency etc.

**What I do:** Take the term list, order by length (desc) to ensure longer matches precede potential substring matches, and join them into a monster `\b(capture|these|words|list)\b`. This is all working basically fine. Generating various case variants for each term would bloat the regex beyond ridiculous; so terms are matched as `i` case-insensitive.

**Problem:** There are some terms that should *only* ever be matched in uppercase or title case, e.g. `IT` or `WHO`, `Will` or `Sandy`. If every `it` and `will` is also matched, it generates a ridiculous volume of noise matches to review. Having "Name" terms confused at the start of a sentence is not really an issue here; and there's no technical way to tell them apart anyway.

**Required**: I need to come up with a *case-insensitive* regex with a large capture group, inside which *indicated options* are handled as *case-sensitive* instead. As far as I can tell, there are no such modifiers that could be attached to individual capture groups or parts thereof. What other approaches do we have in the toolbox?

**Sample Code:**

```
$rx = '~\b(iterations|coffee|random|Will|IT)\b~i';

$texts = [
    'Complex iterations, coffee and IT infrastructure', // should match "iterations", "IT"
    'We will call them Iterations later on', // should match "Iterations"
    'On matters of IT, we have pondered much', // should match "IT"
    'No matched bits and it is for the great good.' // should not match
];

$result = array_map(function($text) use ($rx) {
    preg_match_all($rx, $text, $match);
    return $match;
}, $texts);

var_dump($result);
```

*Any solutions?* Aside a second round of matching to filter out unwanted cases with a case-sensitive regex? It would mean checking for matches with an "unwanted" case of certain terms, but also do not have other "wanted" terms. Doable, but I would prefer if the business logic here could be kept to a single regex, to keep this more portable.

---

*P.S. I've read [Combine case sensitive and insensitive regex...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717319/combine-case-sensitive-regex-and-case-insensitive-regex-into-one) and it doesn't cover this.*

**Update:** It *is* possible to use inline modifiers in capture groups! Thanks, Wiktor. For my case, `(?-i:Will|IT))` would do it. The global `i` flag is canceled with`-i` for a specific capture group. There's an excellent answer on [*Can you make just part of a regex case-insensitive?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58818125/4630325) with more details and implementation in various languages.

Comment: `$rx = '~\b(iterations|coffee|random|(?-i:Will|IT))\b~i';`

Comment: OMG it _is_ possible to use inline modifiers. Thank you @WiktorStribiżew! Spent a fair while looking, how come that didn't show up. I may need a searching refresher. I have closed this question, and whomever with the powers, could you please add top a "duplicate" link with this as the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632/can-you-make-just-part-of-a-regex-case-insensitive/58818125

Comment: Flagged moderator attention. FYI: whoever closed this logged a duplicate that was _explicitly stated_ in the OP as _not addressing the issue_. There is an actual answer that addresses the question linked in my comment above. *No need to reopen, just please update the dupe* so this question retains some referential value.